# Array is empty, how to validate

Tags: arrays, vb.net, ssis, filesystems

I'm working on a program to delete files from a certain folder after they have aged a certain amount of time and either match via regex or extension. I'm running into an issue where files() could be

```
files(0) = Nothing 
files(1) = Nothing
files(2) = Nothing
ect....
```

Right now the way it is written, I could place

```
Else
                            log(1) = data(1)
                            log(3) = "Array field empty"
                            InsertLog(log)
```

and the program would log as many files as `file(i) = Nothing` holds. This would create redundant database records and is not wanted. Is there a way to figure out if ALL `files(i) = Nothing` and then place code in there to insert into the database?

```
           'If log(3) is successful that means no files were old enough or deleted successfully
           If log(3) = "Success" And IsArray(files) Then 
                For Each file In files
                    If Not file.IsNullOrEmpty(file) Then
                        'If files is actually something insert into the log
                        log(1) = file
                        InsertLog(log)
                    'could place else here 
                    End If
                Next
                files = Nothing
            Else
                'If no files or error in directory perform this
                log(1) = data(1)
                InsertLog(log)
            End If
```

Comment: Could you not just look at [File.GetLastWriteTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getlastwritetime.aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a counter to count if a file actually exists, simple solution.

```
           If log(3) = "Success" And IsArray(files) Then
                j = 0
                For Each file In files
                    If Not file.IsNullOrEmpty(file) Then
                        log(1) = file
                        InsertLog(log)
                        j += 1
                    End If
                Next
                If j = 0 Then
                    log(3) = "Files not old enough"
                    InsertLog(log)
                End If
                files = Nothing
            Else
                log(1) = data(1)
                InsertLog(log)
            End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are complicating it too much.

1. Create a timestamp in the database when a file was created
2. Periodically wake up and check if anything needs to be deleted
3. Delete anything needing a delete

Sometimes, when things get too complicated maybe it is time to re-think your attack plan.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function AllArrayElementsAreNull(arr() As Object) As Boolean
    Dim FoundNonNullItem As Boolean = False
    For Each item As Object In Arr
        If item IsNot Nothing Then
            FoundNonNullItem = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Return Not FoundNonNullItem
End Function
```